# Why are some preprocessor macros not expanded unless they are arguments to another macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, pragma

In certain situations, some token sequences are not preprocessed fully.
For example:

```
#define EMPTY()
#define DELAY(x) x EMPTY()
#define PRAGMA(args) _Pragma(args)

#define WRAP( BODY ) { BODY }

#define LOOP_Good( body, i, LB, UB ) \
WRAP( \
    DELAY(PRAGMA)("omp parallel for") \
    for( i = LB; i < UB; ++i ){ \
        body \
    } \
)

#define LOOP_Bad( body, i, LB, UB ) \
{ \
    DELAY(PRAGMA)("omp parallel for") \
    for( i = LB; i < UB; ++i ){ \
        body \
    } \
}

#define LOOP_Good_Again( body, i, LB, UB ) \
{ \
    PRAGMA("omp parallel for") \
    for( i = LB; i < UB; ++i ){ \
        body \
    } \
}

// Good
int i;
int lower_i = 0;
int upper_i = 10;

LOOP_Good( printf("%d\n", i);, i, lower_i, upper_i )

// Bad
LOOP_Bad( printf("%d\n", i);, i, lower_i, upper_i )

// Good again
LOOP_Good_Again( printf("%d\n", i);, i, lower_i, upper_i )
```

Which (using `-E -fopenmp` gcc 9.1) expands to the below (with formatting):

```
int i;
int lower_i = 0;
int upper_i = 10;

// Good
{ 
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for( i = lower_i; i < upper_i; ++i ){ 
    printf("%d\n", i); 
  } 
}

// Bad
{ 
  PRAGMA ("omp parallel for") 
  for( i = lower_i; i < upper_i; ++i ){ 
    printf("%d\n", i); 
  } 
}

// Good again
{ 
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for( i = lower_i; i < upper_i; ++i ){ 
    printf("%d\n", i); 
  } 
}
```

In the 'good' case, the `DELAY(PRAGMA)` is expanded to `PRAGMA` which is then expanded (with the adjacent arguments) to `_Pragma(...)`

In the 'bad' case, the `DELAY(PRAGMA)` is expanded to `PRAGMA` but the processing stops and `PRAGMA` is left in the output.
If you take the 'bad' output and repreprocess it (with all the previously defined macros) it correctly expands.

The only difference is that the 'good' case, `DELAY(PRAGMA)` is part of the argument to the `WRAP` macro, where as the 'bad' case does not pass `DELAY(PRAGMA)` into any macro. If in the 'bad' case, we instead use `PRAGMA` alone, the problem is solved (as in the 'good again' case).

What's the reason for the different behaviors in the 'good' and 'bad' cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bad case, what you intend to be arguments to `PRAGMA` never appear with `PRAGMA` in tokens that are scanned for macro replacement.

We can ignore the `LOOP_xxx` macros; they just expand to various tokens without complications, and the resulting tokens are processed as if they appeared in the source file normally. We can instead consider just `DELAY(PRAGMA)(foo)` and `WRAP(DELAY(PRAGMA)(foo)`.

Per C 2018 6.10.3.1 and 6.10.3.4, the arguments of a macro are processed for macro replacement, then the resulting tokens are substituted into the macro’s replacement tokens, then the resulting tokens and subsequent tokens of the source file are rescanned for further replacement. (When the tokens of a macro argument are being processed, they are treated as if they constitute the entire source file.)

In `DELAY(PRAGMA)(foo)`:

1. `PRAGMA` is the argument `x` to `DELAY`, but it is not followed by parentheses, so it is not a macro to replace.
2. `PRAGMA` is substituted for `x` in `DELAY`’s replacement tokens `x EMPTY()`.
3. The result, `PRAGMA EMPTY()`, is scanned for replacement.
4. EMPTY is replaced by nothing.
5. The results of the replacement of EMPTY, along with the subsequent tokens (`(foo)`, and anything that follows it) are scanned. Note that `PRAGMA` is **not** in these tokens: It is not part of the tokens that resulted from replacing `EMPTY`.
6. Macro replacement is complete.

In `WRAP(PRAGMA)(foo)`, the first five steps are the same, and the remaining steps result in replacement of `PRAGMA (foo)`:

1. `PRAGMA` is the argument `x` to `DELAY`, but it is not followed by parentheses, so it is not a macro to replace.
2. `PRAGMA` is substituted for `x` in `DELAY`’s replacement tokens `x EMPTY()`.
3. The result, `PRAGMA EMPTY()`, is scanned for replacement.
4. EMPTY is replaced by nothing.
5. The results of the replacement of EMPTY, along with the subsequent tokens (`(foo)`) are scanned. As above, `PRAGMA` is not in these tokens, so it is not replaced.
6. Macro replacement of the argument to `WRAP` is complete, having produced `PRAGMA (foo)`.
7. These tokens from the argument are substituted into `WRAP`’s `{ BODY }`, producing `{ PRAGMA (foo) }`.
8. These tokens (along with following tokens in the source file) are rescanned for further replacement. Now `PRAGMA (foo)` appears in these tokens, so it is replaced.

Comment: > the resulting tokens and subsequent tokens of the source file are rescanned for further replacement.
Ah, so the whole file is *not* scanned; rather all of the tokens from the current expansion to the end of the file?
That make's sense but is very annoying.